# React error handling: Error is undefined outside of .catch()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise

I am trying to dynamically display an error message on my save confirmation dialog, if there is one. I am trying to catch the error from a promise, then inset that into the element. However, is is coming up undefined, even though the error message is available from the scope of the 'catch' block. How can I fix this?

```
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false)
  let errorMessage: string = '';

  const onClickSave = async () =>
    setDialog({
      content: (
        <div>
          <h1 className="text-xl">Confirmation</h1>
          <p className="text-md">Are you sure you want to save?</p>
          {
            isError && 
            <p className='text-md text-red-500'>{errorMessage}</p> 
          } 
          // ^^ isError and errorMessage not defined here
          <div className="flex justify-end gap-2">

            <button
              onClick={() => setDialog()}>
              Cancel
            </button>
            <SubmitButton
              loadingContent="Saving"
              onClick={async () => {
                await onSave()
                  .catch(function ({ error }) {
                    errorMessage = error
                    setIsError(true);
                  });
                {
                  !errorMessage && //<--- but they are defined here
                    setDialog();
                }
              }}>
              Save
            </SubmitButton>
          </div>
        </div>
      ),
    });
```

Comment: Store the error message in a state. `const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState()`. And set the error message as `setErrorMessage(error)`. Also, doing this way you can also remove the need for `isError` state and create a const instead `const isError = !!errorMessage`. Will do the same thing and work

Comment: But I am confused about what is going on with your `onClick` function. You have a function inside the `onClick` that runs await `onSave`, attached a `.catch` and outside of the `catch`, still in the `onClick` function, you create an object with `!errorMessage && setDialog();`? Did you mean to do it inside the button child (HTML)? The flow of your `onClick` is confusing and doubt it actually works...